# How do I fix SNAT Exhaustion in App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, httpclient

I'm having a problem with SNAT exhaustion in one of our Azure App Service based APIs:

[image: SNAT]

Our HTTPClient is written into a singleton that should instance only once (C#/.net 4.72)...

```
    public class CSClient : HttpClient
    {
        private static readonly CSClient Inst = new CSClient();

        static CSClient()
        {
        }

        private CSClient() : base()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***.BaseURL"]);
        }

        public static HttpClient Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return Inst;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then called

```
public class ContentRepository : IContentRepository
    {
        protected HttpClient htc = CSClient.Instance;

        public async Task<Content> GetContentAsync(Content ct)
        {
            using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***.BaseUrl"] + "/api/v2/nodes/" + ct.Id))
            {
                var response = await htc.SendAsync(req);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var job = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    var respct = OTtoContent(job["results"]);
                    return respct;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why the extra connections are being made. Is my singleton correct? Anything else I can do with the httpclient? Anything to do with the app service, short of adding resources? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is potential solution: [SNAT with App Service](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/)

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient allow multiple requests in parallel to the same endpoint(by default).

[The following methods are thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2):

1. CancelPendingRequests
2. DeleteAsync
3. List item
4. GetAsync
5. GetByteArrayAsync
6. GetStreamAsync
7. GetStringAsync
8. PostAsync
9. PutAsync
10. SendAsync

So one instance of `HttpClient` can make several connections at a time via `SendAsync`. You can try to control number of connections via [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or [HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netframework-4.7.2)(on [Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/timomta/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework)) property.